# How to test restful webservices with Mocha and Chai

Tags: node.js, web-services, mocha.js, chai, server-sent-events

I'm new to writing unit tests and I'm trying to learn Mocha and Chai. In my Node+express project I've created a unit test like this:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
var EventSource = require('eventsource');

describe('Connection tests', () => { // the tests container
    it('checks for connection', () => { // the single test
        var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/prenotazione?subscribe=300');
        source.onmessage = function(e: any) {
          expect(false).to.equal(true);
        };
    });
});
```

The `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/prenotazione?subscribe=300` webservice is active when the test executes and I can see that Mocha does call it, because my webservice logs the incoming request. That webservice is using [the SSE protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) and it never closes the connection, but it keeps sending data now and then over the same connection. [EventSource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventsource) is the client class that implements the SSE protocol, and it connects to the server when you set the `onmessage` callback into it. However Mocha does not wait for the webservice to return and the test passes whatever I write into `expect` function call. For example, only to debug the test code itself, I even wrote `expect(false).to.equal(true);` that obviously can never be true. However here is what I get when I run the test:

```
$ npm run test

> crud@1.0.0 test
> mocha -r ts-node/register test/**/*.ts --exit



  Connection tests
    ✔ checks for connection


  1 passing (23ms)
```

How do I make Mocha wait for the webservice to return data before resolving the test as passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few trials end errors, I found that

1. When Mocha unit tests need to wait for something, they must return a Promise
2. EventSource npm package (which is NOT 100% compatible with the native EventSource Javascript object), for some reason, maybe always, maybe only when used in Mocha or whatever, does not call the `onmessage` handler, so you have to add the event listener using the alternative `addEventListener` function

Here is my working code:

```
describe('SSE Protocol tests', () => {
    it('checks for notifications on data changes', function () { 
        this.timeout(0);
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, _reject) => {
          var eventSourceInitDict = {https: {rejectUnauthorized: false}};
          var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/prenotazione?subscribe=3600', eventSourceInitDict);
          var count = 2;
          source.addEventListener("results", function(event: any) {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            count--;
            if(count == 0)  {
              resolve(true);
            }       
          });
        }).then(value => {
          assert.equal(typeof(value), 'boolean');
          assert.equal(value, true);
        }, error => {
          assert(false, error);
        });
    });
});
```